# Pyqt6 multiscreen popup bug

Tags: python, virtual-machine, pyqt6, windows-11, multiscreen

I'm developing an app with pyqt6 on Windows 11 on a virtual machine with a multiscreen setup and I'm encountering problems with combobox popup-windows and tooltips. It seems that the the frames of these widgets don't move along with the main widget if it goes to a different screen. Instead the popup windows and tooltips stay at the side of the primary window at the position closest to the main widget.

[image]

[image]

I've tried moving the combobox.view() manually but that just moves the popup relatifly on the primary screen but in now way on to any of the other screens. I've tried using function like repaint(), setParent(), mapToGlobal() but none of them seem to work. At this point I don't even know what to look for. Has anybody encountered this before and does know what can be done?

Comment: Possibly related to [QTBUG-106099](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-106099). Check that your version of Qt (not PyQt!) is at least that indicated in the "Fix Version/s" field and eventually update.